# Templates without T parameters in a non-template class

Tags: c++, qt, templates

Ok, I read a lot of answers here and there about this problem, but probably since I don't know the proper syntax I can't figure out how to do this.

I have a non-template class which has to implement different static utility functions, mainly for serialization and deserialization. What I currently have is something like this:

```
class Data_Base : public QObject
{
    ...
protected:
    static QByteArray Serialize(int value);
    static int DeserializeInt(QByteArray ser);
    static QByteArray Serialize(char *value);
    static char *DeserializeCharArr(QByteArray ser);
    static QByteArray Serialize(QString value);
    static QString DeserializeQString(QByteArray ser);
    ....
}
```

Now, I'd prefer to have all the `Deserialize*` function as a template, since it will be nicer. And as a bonus, have also the `Serialize` functions as templates, so I will force the user to actually explicitely say which overload to call. Something which can be used this way:

```
QByteArray ba = Serialize<int>(5);
...
int theValue = Deserialize<int>(ba);
```

Now, I've tried different approaches, but since all the functions I saw only examples implementing the templates automatically and not one overload at a time I couldn't find out how to make this work.

Of course this is C++, with QT additions.

Comment: The term you seem to be looking for is *specialization*, not overloading. Do a search on *c++ template specialization*.

Comment: Templates are useful when the code is the same for each type. If your functions are different in according to the data structure, a smart function overload is the best solution

Comment: If it's about centralizing things so that changing something in one changes it in all, how about them calling an extern function? static QByteArray Serialize(int value){ return extern_serialize<QByteArray>(value);} for all of them, probably combined with making the extern function a friend.

Comment: It may be useful if you provide a minimal explanation about your `Serialize` method. At least what *input parameters* and *output* work. For example `Serialize(int)`, what does `int` mean?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you. As I thought, I don't know the correct terms. Anyway I already tried something like this, but the compiler said `error: explicit specialization in non-namespace`. Does this mean that you cannot write a template function in a class definition? I think so, because on [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization) they say that "Explicit specialization can only appear at namespace scope"

Comment: @BiagioFesta I agree, but in this case it was a sort of "nicer" way to expose thems. Anyway the serialize method "serializes" something, while deserialize.. well, deserializes. Serialization means converting something (an integer, a string, an object) to a byte array, while deserialization is the opposite operation (so extracting that from the byte array). It's a common operation used to send data over the network or to store it in a file, so I thought it was self-explanatory (but in the end it wasn't). Anyhow the question is not about this, but just about declaring template methods in a class

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, it is called template specialization and looks like this:

```
class X
{
    public:
    template<typename T>
    static QByteArray Serialize(T const& t);

    template<typename T>
    static T Deserialize(QByteArray& v);
};

template<>
QByteArray X::Serialize(int const& t)
{
    /* ... */
}

template<>
QByteArray X::Serialize(QString const& t)
{
    /* ... */
}

template<>
int X::Deserialize(QByteArray& v)
{
    /* ... */
}

template<>
QString X::Deserialize(QByteArray& v)
{
    /* ... */
}

QByteArray x=X::Serialize(5);
int y=X::Deserialize<int>(x);
```

When using `Serialize` you do not need to specify the template parameter because it can be deduced from the argument's
type.

But you cannot deduce by return type, so you need to add the template parameter when using `Deserialize`.

Comment: Thank you. I already tried this solution before posting, but if I try to write this code inside a class the compiler says `error: explicit specialization in non-namespace`. Does this mean that you cannot write a template function in a class definition?

Comment: @frarugi87 I edited the answer using a class. You probably put the specialization inside the class definition. It has to be outside, the class definition only holds the declaration of the prototype.

Comment: This appears to work. The only thing to do when splitting the declaration and the definition in header and source file is to add `template<> QByteArray X::Serialize(int value);` (and so on) at the end of the header file, outside the class definition. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

IMO force your solution with the usage of template specialization could be a bad choice design.

As I've already said in a comment, templates are generally good when your code structure is equal for each data type.

Serialization is a delicate operation (casting, raw memory, etc.) and data structure can define different implicit conversions and produce an UB.

---

If I had to implement an a *"template"* behaviour, this would be the first solution (just a scratch!):

```
struct Foo {
  // Some data member variables.
  std::string m_nopod;

  // Serialize data object. 'It' must to be a output iterator
  template<typename It>
  void serialize(It out_iterator) {
    constexpr size_t BYTES_FOR_SIZE = sizeof(decltype(m_nopod.size()));
    constexpr size_t BYTES_FOR_CHAR = sizeof(decltype(m_nopod)::value_type);

    // size definitions.
    const auto len_str = m_nopod.size();
    const auto len_data = BYTES_FOR_CHAR * len_str;

    // Temporary memory buffers.
    uint8_t memory_size[BYTES_FOR_SIZE];
    auto memory_data = std::make_unique<uint8_t[]>(len_data);

    // Raw bytes copy.
    std::memcpy(memory_size, &len_str, BYTES_FOR_SIZE);
    std::memcpy(memory_data.get(), m_nopod.data(), len_data);

    // write with the iterator.
    for (size_t i = 0; i < BYTES_FOR_SIZE; ++i) {
      *out_iterator = memory_size[i];
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < len_data; ++i) {
      *out_iterator = memory_data[i];
    }
  }
};
```

Where the `out_iterator` must to be a [`output_iterator`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/OutputIterator/), and `::value_type` must to be a implicit convertible type to `unsigned char`.

The function can be invoked with different data structures (containers):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::vector<char> memory_buffer_char;
  std::vector<int> memory_buffer_int;
  std::string memory_buffer_str;

  Foo foo{"a_string"};

  foo.serialize(std::back_inserter(memory_buffer_char));
  foo.serialize(std::back_inserter(memory_buffer_int));
  foo.serialize(std::back_inserter(memory_buffer_str));
  return 0;
}
```

---

As I've already said, however, I'll never adopt that solution. Rather I'm going to use a simple overloading of function for those various types.

In order avoid writing same thing more than once, I'll define a unique helper function (a private method) which contains the logic of the class.

For example the helper function could create an ordinary buffer of memory in which to serialize the class (array of char) and then overloaded functions should only adapt that array in the proper input data structure.

In that way when the class logic (e.g., data members) changes, you should modify only the helper function.